# Import Filezilla sites from a windows computer

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10, ftp

I have a Win10 host computer running Filezilla 3.21.0

I have an Oracle VirtualBox guest running Ubuntu 15.04 and Filezilla 3.9.0.5

If I export my sites from my Windows host system and import them in my Ubuntu guest system, then attempt to access the Site Manager, I get errors like this:

```
An assertion failed
server.cpp(521): assert "logonType != LOGONTYPE_MAX" failed in SetLogonType().
```

If I go into /home/myuser/.config/filezilla and remove the "sitemanager.xml" file, everything seems to work correctly again.

My assumption is that there's a conflict either between the numeric versions or the platform versions, but I'm not sure what to try next.

TLDR:
How can I import Win10 Filezilla Site Manager entries into Filezilla on Ubuntu?

Comment: Try upgrading to a more recent version of FileZilla for Ubuntu. I just installed it recently via the Ubuntu Software app on a 16.04 LTS box and got version 3.15.0.2. When I exported the Site Manager information and compared it to an export from version 3.21.0 on Windows the (XML) files were identical, and the Windows file imported into the Ubuntu version without incident.

Comment: I'll see what I can find. I installed once with apt-get and once through the software center. Pretty sure they use the same repo. I'll see if I can get it directly from filezilla-project.org.

Comment: @GordThompson, If you would make your comment into an answer, I'll accept it. I'm also going to self-answer with good detail.

Comment: You go ahead and post your answer. I'll be interested to see the details.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is apparently a numeric version problem, as suggested by @GordThompson. The version available in the repo for 15.04 is too old.

I downloaded the new version (3.21.0) from filezilla-project.org's sourceforge link. It was a gzip file that contained a directory called "Filezilla 3" that contained a "bin" and "share" directory. I extracted them inside my downloads directory,  opened thunar as root with `pkexec thunar` copied `/bin` & `/share` then pasted them into `/usr`, accepting any overwrite requests.

I opened filezilla, imported my Filezilla.xml file and all seems to work fine!

Comment: be VERY careful running thunar as root! You can really break stuff!